# NBA 2k14 PC - Are there any story based cutscenes like on the next gen consoles?

Tags: pc, nba2k14

I don't have the game yet, and i read that the game graphics are current gen etc. but i couldn't really find any answers to this:

Are there any story based cutscenes like on the next gen consoles?
Not just the aftergame press like in NBA 2k13, but cutscenes like in NBA 2k15 and 2k14 on Next Gen consoles.